# Solving inequalities with absolute values

Tags: inequality, problem-solving, absolute-value

This is the question:

$$ 
\left| \frac{x+2}{3(x-1)} \right| \leq \frac{2}{3}
$$

And this is my working out, first I squared both the numerator and denominator, then solved it as if it was a normal inequality.

$$
\frac{(x+2)^2}{(3x-3)^2} \leq \frac{2}{3}
$$

$$
3(x+2)^2 \leq 2(3x-3)^2
$$

$$
9x^2 +36x+36 \leq 36x^2 -72x+36
$$

I took out a common factor of 9

$$
x^2 +5x+4 \leq 4x^2-8x+4
$$

$$
3x^2 -12x \geq 
\\
x(3x-4) \geq 0
\\
x \geq 0 \text{ and } x \geq \frac{4}{3}
$$

Usually, when dealing with inequalities like this, I end up with a quadratic equation, which I am then able to factorise and solve correctly,but I'm not sure what went wrong with this one. The correct answer is

$$
x \leq 0
\\
x \geq 4
$$

What have I done wrong, thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you can square only one side of the inequality and still preserve the sign? $2<3$ but $4>3$ would be a simple counter example without considering which sign is being used as $-3<0$ but $9>0$ for another example here as each could be expressed as a fraction with a denominator of 1.

Comment: Minor algebra error, $3x^2-12x=3x(x-4)$. Somehow you got $x(3x-4)$. Apart from that minor slip, everything is fine. In particular, the reasoning is perfectly correct.

Comment: Yes that was the mistake, a very, very stupid mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is sound. First a preliminary comment. The left-hand side is not defined at $x=1$, so whatever answer we get must exclude $1$.

We have
$$\left|\frac{x+2}{3(x-1)}\right|\le \frac{2}{3}\quad\text{if and only if}\quad \left(\frac{x+2}{3(x-1)}\right)^2\le \frac{4}{9}.$$
If $x\ne 1$, then the equality on the right above holds if and only if
$$9(x+2)^2 \le (4)(9)(x-1)^2.$$
The above inequality reduces quickly to $(9)(3)(x)(x-4)\ge 0$, which holds precisely if $x\le 0$ or $x\ge 4$.

The point $x=1$ is not in the region just obtained, so we need not worry about it.

**Remark:** The procedure used in the post was sound. It was presented as a manipulation. The logic should have been made clearer (as in the "if and only if" of the answer above).

There was a minor arithmetical slip. It is not true that $3x^2-12x=x(3x-4)$.

Comment: What an idiot, of all mistakes factorising had to be it, thank you so much for noticing it! I was probably rushing, I need to be more accuracte, thank you again!

Comment: And that's correct, next to the question it said $x \neq 1$, I should have stated that earlier, thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

The inequality reduces to two separate inequalities:

They are $$ 
\frac{x+2}{3(x-1)} \leq \frac{2}{3}
$$

and

$$ 
-\frac{x+2}{3(x-1)} \leq \frac{2}{3}
$$

Solving the first one $$(x+2) \leq 2(x-1)$$
$$x\geq 4$$

Solving the second one $$x+2\geq 2-2x$$

$$3x\leq 0$$

$$x \leq 0$$

Comment: The reasoning of OP was perfectly OK. Just a minor error in arithmetic.

Comment: @Andre, In this case, it was OK.  For an inequality such as $\abs{\frac{x+5}{x+2}}\geq 2$.  If you don't square and solve it, inequality will give you $x\leq 1$ squaring on one side will yield a different range for x?  Am I mistaken in my understanding?

Comment: Thank you! Now I know another method, thank you again!

Comment: An inequality of the shape $|f(x)|\le a$, where $a\ge 0$, is **equivalent** to $(f(x))^2\le a^2$. However, squaring is not a universal tool even in such cases: it may complicate things excessively. And the cases tool that you used is quite a bit more "universal."

Comment: Understood, Thanks.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, are you a professor and if so where are you teaching?

Comment: Yes, the pedantic style is difficult to hide.

Comment: +1. However, the final result $(x\ge4$ or $x\le0)$ is correct but not the intermediate solutions. The first inequation $\frac{x+2}{3(x-1)} \leq \frac{2}{3}$ is not equivalent to $x\ge4,$ but to $x\ge4$ or $x<1.$ The second inequation $-\frac{x+2}{3(x-1)} \leq \frac{2}{3}$ is not equivalent to $x\le0,$ but to $x\le0$ or $x>1.$