# Inequalities containing terms in modulus function

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

Solve the following inequality :- $3x+2<|2x+5|<8x+9$

I need help in verifying if my method of solving is correct

---

I splitted this into 2 inequalities

A) $3x+2<|2x+5|$

Then squared both sides, $(3x+2)^2<(2x+5)^2$

this gave me x in the range $(-7/3 , 3)$

B) similarly did for $|2x+5|<8x+9$ and got x in the range $(-7/5,-2/3)$

The common range comes out to be $(-2/3 , 3)$

Is this process correct to solve inequalities by squaring the terms to remove that modulus function ?

Also, is there any further check I need to put in at the end to ensure that the range is correct if I square the terms initially which could potentially reduce my range?

Comment: "Squaring both sides" is not correct. $a<|b|$ does not imply $a^2<b^2.$ For instance $-2<|1|$ but $(-2)^2>1^2.$

Comment: why is not correct ? can you provide an example in which it wont work ?

Comment: Similarly in B): $a^2<b^2$ does not imply $|a|<b.$

Comment: Thank you @AnneBauval, I somehow got the correct answer with faulty logic xD... if it would have been |3x+2|<|2x+5|, would my process work in that case ?

Comment: In that case it would be true, since both sides are positives.

Comment: You have not "somehow got the correct answer".

Comment: And yes, squaring both sides won't potentially lead to the correct equation. When solving inequalities with the absolute value involved, you should deduce when it is zero and then do a case distinction.

Comment: with reference to this post :- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712807/solving-inequalities-with-absolute-values?rq=1   ; the solutions have used squaring both sides , so is it incorrect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the exact same thing as you but with domain restrictions will give you the right answer as following :

**Case-1**
$$|2x+5|<8x+9$$
clearly for this to be true in any case whatsoever $8x+9>0$ must be true. Now squaring under this condition we get

$$(2x+5)^2<(8x+9)^2 \implies(6x+4)(10x+14)>0$$
$$\implies x \in (-\infty,-1.4)\ \cup\ \left(-\frac{2}{3}, \infty \right)$$

Now taking intersection with the $8x+9>0$ condition we get

$$x \in\left(-\frac{2}{3}, \infty \right) $$

---

**Case-2**
$$3x+2<|2x+5|$$
As noted by **@Anne Bauval** in the comments one obvious solution in this case would be $3x+2 <0 \implies x < -\frac{2}{3}$
and the other part of solution set comes from squaring the equation as follows
$$(3x+2)^2<(2x+5)^2\implies (x-3)(5x+7)<0 \implies x \in \left(-\frac{7}{5} , 3\right)$$

so complete solution set for **Case-2** will be the union of both solutions :

$$x \in \left(-\infty , 3\right)$$

---

Taking the intersection of both cases we finally get

$$x \in  \left(-\frac{2}{3},3\right)$$

In conclusion always write the domain restrictions and *check for obvious cases* (applicable to me too ;) ) before squaring up inequalities as squaring always gives botched solutions.

Comment: The final result is correct, but not the reasoning in case 2 from "we don't need any restriction we can directly square it up". $a<|b|$ is not equivalent to $a^2<b^2$ but to $a^2<b^2$ or $a<0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval yeah you are correct ...  I should edit this in

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the definition of the modulus: $|2x+5| = 2x+5$ if $x\ge-5/2$ and $|2x+5| = -2x-5$ if $x \lt -5/2$. If $x\ge -5/2$ then the original inequality can be rewritten without the modulus and solved as follows:

$$3x+2\lt 2x+5 \lt 8x+9$$
$$-x+3\lt 5x+7$$
$$ 0\lt 6x+4$$
$$ x\gt -2/3$$

Now to solve for the upper bound:

$$3x+2\lt 2x+5 \lt 8x+9$$
$$-5x-7 \lt -6x-4$$
$$x-3 \lt 0$$
$$x \lt 3$$

Therefore, this inequality holds when $-2/3 \lt x \lt 3$. You can use the definition of the modulus to check the case of $2x+5 \lt 0$ to confirm the result.

Comment: Small calculation mistake: the solution of $0\lt 6x+4$ is $x>-2/3,$ not $-3/2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval argh, god damn it! I edited it to -3/2 because I thought I got it wrong with -2/3 lol. Cheers for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

As commented, "squaring both sides" like you did is not correct. Anyway, in this context, introducing and solving *quadratic* inequations was overcomplicated. Instead, you could apply the three following simple rules: $$|t|=\max(t,-t)$$
$$a<\max(b,c)\iff(a<b\text{ or }a<c)$$
$$\max(b,c)<d\iff(b<d\text{ and }c<d).$$

A) $$\begin{align}3x+2<|2x+5|&\iff(3x+2<2x+5\text{ or }3x+2<-2x-5)\\&\iff x<\max(3,-7/5)=3.
\end{align}$$

B)
$$\begin{align}|2x+5|<8x+9&\iff(2x+5<8x+9\text{ and }-2x-5<8x+9)\\&\iff x>\max(-2/3,-7/5)=-2/3.
\end{align}$$

> "The common range comes out to be $(-2/3 , 3)$" indeed,

but this was not the case with your $(-7/3,3)\cap(-7/5,-2/3)=(-7/5,-2/3).$

In [the post you mention in comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712807),
"squaring both sides" was legit to solve $|a|\le b$ (because $b$ was known to be positive) but again, overcomplicated compared to solving directly $(a\le b$ and $-a\le b).$ See @AndréNicolas' comment to [the non-accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712824/386889), which was however [not quite correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/712824/timeline#comment_10002920).

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I am still confused when can we square the modulus functions and we cannot, could you please summarise the conditions for me

Comment: $a^2\le b^2\iff|a|\le|b|,$ and $|x|=x\iff x\ge0.$ But squaring to solve $|a|\le|b|$ is overcomplicating things. $|a|\le|b|\iff(a\le|b|$ and $-a\le|b|),$ and $x\le|b|\iff(x\le b$ or $x\le-b).$